# Probability problem: about a radioactive substance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A substance undergoes radioactive decay by emitting particles at random times. Observation shows that the probability of an emission is proportional to the observation time, in the limit of small observation times. Suppose that empirical data show that the substance emits $200$ particles per minute, on the average. What is the probability that a $1$-minute count will be exactly $200$?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use the Poisson distribution.

[image: Poisson distribution]

If I am correct, then $λ$ is the expected value, which is $200$.   The number $k$ is the actual number of observations, which is also $200$.

The above formula should give the probability that you will observe exactly $200$ particles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Poisson distribution, Luke:
$$
\frac{\lambda^{200}e^{-200}}{200!}
$$
with $\lambda=200.$

You can approximate this as $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi\cdot200}}$.

Comment: $\lambda = \frac{1}{200}$ or $200$ because the previous answer tell me that $\lambda=200$. Thanks :)

Comment: The parameter value can cause confusion, since for the Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, the parameter is the mean, while for the exponential with parameter $\lambda$, the parameter is the reciprocal of the mean.  To make things worse, the Poisson and the exponential often play together.

Comment: I am probably incorrect.

Comment: @PhiNotPi: Sorry, you're right. I did my calculations with $\lambda=200$ but wrote it as 1/200 for some reason.

Comment: there are some differences between $$\frac{200^{200}e^{-200}}{200!}$$ and $$\frac{1}{2 \pi 200}$$

Comment: @Iuli: I left out the square root bar, sorry!